# Exchange bathroom fan

Tags: fans

I moved to the new condo and found that fan works loud.

The sound meter showed that the noise level during operation of central ventilation (without fan) is between 46 and 49 dB (it is the average data for 15 minutes with silence in all rooms). During the night the noise seems very "loud".

The installed fan is Épurair EP100 G (or EP100G2V (2 speed)). Based on the characteristic of Épurair EP100 G, the sones should be 0.8 (the fan is rated at 0.8 sone, which equals 32 dB).

Verification by the sound meter showed that the noise level of installed fan is between 46 and 49 dB. Sins an 1 sone is equivalent to 40 dB, I can assume that the noise level of  Épurair EP100 G2V is around 1.15-1.2 sones. I do not understand this discrepancy (0.8 is in technical characteristics and 1.2 sones are in reality). That seems a bit loud, doesn't it?

May I ask you: which Panasonic model will be fit for replacement of EP100G2V (2 speed)? 2 speed, because the fan is making airflow for the whole condo (breaker for slow speed is in the room), but for using the bathroom is another breaker in the bathroom who makes a speed up.

I found one Panasonic model: Panasonic FV-08-11VF5 Whisperfit EZ Retrofit fan. Is it good for change old one(Épurair EP100 G2V).

Comment: We're not going to know what bathroom fan will fit withough getting a lot more detail about the fans and the hole they go into, and thats probably not practical for this question.  I can say that builders usually put in the cheapest (and loudest) fans, so anything you can get that claims to be quieter should be an improvement.  Your testing might not match the sound level advertised on the package, but you can still use it as a guide to select a quieter fan.

Comment: Sound level testing is done under ideal conditions. Things like flex ducting, or long runs with a bunch of elbows increases the noise level. A fan with a lower rating will create less noise but don't expect the advertised level unless you match the ducting to the test conditions. This also includes the fresh air supply if restricted can cause the fan to speed up and vibrate more than test conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The Panasonic fans are an excellent choice.  They are quiet and very efficient.  Broan/Nutone also makes excellent products.  I would recommend the new low sone models. Bath fans have a definite life expectancy. As they get older the bearing in the motor dry out and the noise level go up, up, up.  Either of these would make a good replacement; minor ceiling modifications may be necessary.  Be sure to vent it to the out of doors.  Because of the low sone quality of the new fans, I doubt the the reduced speed feature will be necessary. I would not recommend trying to incorporate the reduced speed switch with the new fan.  It probably would not be compatible.